# Pydantic with enum subclasses?

Tags: validation, inheritance, enums, subclass, pydantic

So imagine I have something like

```py
class SpecialEnum(Enum):
    def do_stuff(self):
         # some cool operation
```

And then have

```py
class MySpecialEnum(SpecialDescriptorEnum):
   A = 1
   B = 2
```

Then, I have a `pydantic` model with:

```py
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    my_field: SpecialEnum
```

I want pydantic to validate that my_field is some instance of a SpecialEnum subclass.
However, pydantic uses its special enum validator instead, and validates with `SpecialEnum(field_value)` instead, resulting in what will always be a `ValidationError` - since SpecialEnum was only ever meant to provide functionality or interface, and not values.

Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use subclassesinherited from Enum  with "some cool methods"? I think this is not the best option. Usually enum is a container for constants value not for methods. According to enum documentation: "An enumeration is a set of symbolic names (members) bound to unique, constant values". more: https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html
You probably need different solution. Please add more details and maybe we will be able to help you.

Comment: I agree with @JacekK. A mixin or a protocol could be an alternative.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you actually meant `class MySpecialEnum(SpecialEnum): ...` or is `SpecialDescriptorEnum` something else?

Comment: @JacekK I disagree. To reference that same documentation, they dedicate a whole section to [enum subclassing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#restricted-enum-subclassing). Quote: _"it makes sense to allow sharing some common behavior between a group of enumerations"_. So, while this may arguably be a niche use case, I would argue there is no way to judge whether or not it makes sense in _this_ case based on the limited information provided by OP. He/she might have a good reason for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for a workaround. You can override the default validation by adding the special [`__get_validators__`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#custom-data-types) class method to your base `SpecialEnum` class. Here is a full working example:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from collections.abc import Callable, Iterator
from enum import Enum
from typing import Any

from pydantic import BaseModel


class SpecialEnum(Enum):
    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls) -> Iterator[Callable[..., Any]]:
        yield cls.validate

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, v: SpecialEnum) -> SpecialEnum:
        if not isinstance(v, cls):
            raise TypeError(f"Must be an instance of `{cls.__name__}`")
        return v

    def do_stuff(self) -> None:
        print("stuff", self)


class MySpecialEnum(SpecialEnum):
    A = 1
    B = 2


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    my_field: SpecialEnum


class Unrelated(Enum):
    foo = "foo"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    instance = MyModel(my_field=MySpecialEnum.A)
    instance.my_field.do_stuff()
    # wrong1 = MyModel(my_field=Unrelated.foo)  # causes a `ValidationError`
    # wrong2 = MyModel(my_field=1)  # ALSO causes a `ValidationError`
```

There is a caveat here though. Usually you would be able to define some additional logic to accept the enum member's *value* or even allow the member's *name* and have the validator return the corresponding enum member itself. (The `wrong2` example in the last line.)

But since your validation methods *must* be defined on the *base class* `SpecialEnum` because that is the one you use to annotate `my_field`, there is no way to know *which* enum subclass to check the value/name against.

If that is of interest to you, you might be able to construct some additional logic for that, but I think this will only be possible if you ensure that all enum members of **all** subclasses of `SpecialEnum` are distinct.

Hope this helps.